# Create a function that listens for a change from a BackEnd call in FrontEnd

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, backend, back

Hi fisrt of all thanks for reading and your attention :)

I am learning and I am not sure , but a want do a videocall from one user to other.
Then I have created a call in my backend, which creates the session of the video call and the user token. So now I want to create a kind of listener on client that has to be activated when they are calling you. **I think I have to use WebSockects** but i'm not familiar with them and i'm not sure that's the answer.

Is a web aplication runing with node.js (express) and react js.

Comment: you can refer this https://socket.io/docs/

Comment: Read doc about https://webrtc.org/